# Read a manga half a year ago went to find it was about a martial artist?

Tags: sword-of-the-emperor

I read a manga about half a year ago which is about a Royal Prince or something like that, but his Father gets killed when the throne got taken away from him.

So the Prince has to flee and gets trained by 2 old guys in a cave. He also gets two souls in his body. One soul is from a strong but bad martial artist and another soul from a buddha monk which resides in his body so that the evil soul can't take over his body.

Anyone got an ideas which manga I am looking for?

Would really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a long search I finally found the manhwa (Korean comics) I was looking for.

It's name is [**Sword of the Emperor**](http://myanimelist.net/manga.php?id=45665)

[image: Volume 1 cover]

> **Synopsis**
>
> A young Emperor is cast out of his Empire by his uncle, who seizes the
>   throne for himself. The young Emperor sets out to become the strongest
>   among the living, and take back what is rightfully his.

So thanks for everyone who looked for it or at least tried to think about it :)